# Wrong quantity defined for salary rule odoo 9

Tags: odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo

Can you help me how get number of hours from working days with python code?

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: @user365213 need get number of hours in salary role, my example retur wrong python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if contract.paid_hourly:
    result = 1 * worked_days.WORK01.number_of_hours
else:
    result = 100
```